# Import data from excel to matlab row by row

Tags: excel, matlab, import

I need to know if there is any function that can import data from excel row by row?
I used to work with xlsread but it won't work for this case unless i use it in a function that takes all the columns and group all the element in the same row together...

Edit: I was able to do it using simple xlsread by the following code:

```
num = xlsread(excel_file,'B2:BI174');
row1=num(1:173:end);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "row by row" - do you want to import, say, into a cell array, where each element of a cell contains one row? Or do you want to read one row at a time, because you do not have the RAM needed to import all at once? Does the excel data contain numbers only, or mixed numbers and strings? Are you on Windows?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes i meant each element of a cell contains one row, and the excel file contain number only, and yes i'm on windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is tempting to read the data one row at a time, but that means you will waste time due to file access overhead. It's a lot faster to read all at once and re-pack into a cell array:

```
allData = xlsread('filename.xls');

oneRowPerElementCell = mat2cell(allData, ones(size(allData,1),1), size(allData,2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Read `xlsread` documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html#bthgbma) to read a block from excel file.

Example: To read the first row from 1st to 26th coulmn use,

```
row1 = xlsread('filename.xlsx',sheet_no,'A1:Z1');
```